# "Cucumber Full Support" extension in VS code and I'm facing configuration issues

Tags: testing, visual-studio-code, automation, protractor, cucumber

**Issue:**

-Curly lines are displayed in the feature file even when step definitions are available and properly mentioned in the settings.json file

-Go to step definitions and Peek Step definitions options aren't displayed

**Expected behavior:**

User should be displayed Curly lines only for steps which doesn't have step definitions

User should be able to Go to step definitions from feature files using "Go to Step definition" option on right click

**Settings.json file:**

```
{
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": ["stepDefinitions/*.ts"],
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "featureFiles/*feature",
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinValidation": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.smartSnippets": true,
    "cucumberautocomplete.stepsInvariants": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "cucumberautocomplete.customParameters": [

    ]
}
```

**My Project structure:**

```
-PROJECT NAME
  -featureFiles
    -features1.feature
    -features1.feature
  -stepDefinitions
    -stepDefintions_1.ts
    -stepDefintions_2.ts
    -stepDefintions_3.ts
  -pageObjects
  -logs
  -configFiles
  -commonUtlities
  -node_modules
  -reports
  -package.json
  -ts-config.json
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and include the typescript code for one of your step definitions? Do the tests run?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Sure I'll edit. And my scripts are running and getting passed successfully. There are no issues with actual Cucumber framework, just this extension doesn't work. {Note: This same extension worked just months ago for the same code,for the same set of lines}

Comment: What folder is your .vscode\settings.json in? I think your steps path needs to start from there (i.e. the folder you open in vscode).

Comment: @MonkeyTester Appreciating your help

"cucumberautocomplete.steps": ["C:/Users/Public/Project_Code/Protractor_Workspace/ADCAE/stepDefinitions/*.ts"],
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "C:/Users/Public/Project_Code/Protractor_Workspace/ADCAE/featureFiles/*feature"

I tried giving absolute path too. Yet it didn't help me. Also I tried giving it from the Project name, it also didn't work. And settings.json file is in C folder AppData directory, which is not related to my User's directory.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Done. I used Images to explain it more clear.

Comment: Now there are no images or code. That's not what I meant. Several of the images were useful, as they communicated for than just plain code. You added an image of your step definitions. I meant for you to copy and past the code for your step definitions.

Comment: @GregBurghardt : It has nothing to do with the feature file, nor the step definitions. The settings.json file has the issue, I have to mention the right path in the json file. If my feature file and step definitions have issue, they wont run and generate my reports, but actually they are running smoothly. So we should concentrate on json file. No more Images or code required for this particular question posted.

Answer (score 0):

So this works for me. My settings.json file lives in the .vscode folder, which sits in the folder that I open in vscode (see image). The cucumberautocomplete.steps value is relative to this same folder.
[image]

Comment: Awesome. But I'm not sure where I could find this where I could find this .vscode folder like displayed in your Image.<br/>
For me below is the path is where my settings.json file is available.
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json

I tried like your code, from the project name, yet it didn't work.<br/>

 **"cucumberautocomplete.steps": ["ADCAE/stepDefinitions/*.ts"],<br/>
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "${workspaceFolder}/ADCAE/featureFiles/*feature",**<br/>

_We can connect in TeamViewer, if you can help me on this._

Comment: Just create the folder yourself and copy your settings.json into it. I think settings in here will override the ones in your AppData folder.

Comment: Nope Bro..I tried creating a folder and placing my settings.json file into it, but it didnt work (I deleted old settings.json file from it's origin too). This is really giving me a headache. None was able to solve this. :(

Comment: Adding a dot before "feature" like here:  "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "${workspaceFolder}/ADCAE/featureFiles/*.feature"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And, like you, I tried many variations of path.

Finally, only these settings worked for me:

```
"cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
    "**/*.rb"
],
"cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "**/*.feature",
"cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true,
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": true
}
```